# Ratio of inradii of similar triangles is equal to the ratio of corresponding sides

Tags: geometry

Why are the inradii of similar triangles in the ratio of the corresponding sides of the triangles?

I understand why the same applies to circumradii, medians, altitudes and angle bisectors. But I have no idea how to prove this for inradii of two similar triangles.

**Edit**: I used SAS similarity of triangles to prove that the medians and circumradii  of two similar triangles would be in the ratio of corresponding sides of the triangles. Similarly, I used AA similarity for altitudes and AA similarity for angle bisectors. I would like to know if there's a similar way to prove for the inradii of similar triangles.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... *"I understand why the same applies to circumradii, medians, altitudes and angle bisectors."* What convinces you of the fact in these cases, and where are you getting stuck applying a similar argument to the inradius case? Even if you're not sure how to proceed, sometimes just "thinking out loud" about what you know can be useful ... and it can help answerers avoid explaining things you already understand. (Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4616096/edit) to add context or clarifications. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s$ be the semiperimeter of a triangle with the sides $a, b$ and $c$:

$$
s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}
$$

Then, by [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), the area $A$ of the triangle is

$$
A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$$

The length of the inradius $r$ is

$$
r=\frac{A}{s}
$$

Not lets create a similar triangle with the stretching factor $f$, so that its sides are $a'=af;\,b'=bf;\,c'=cf$. The semiperimeter $s'$ of the similar triangle is

$$
s'=\frac{af+bf+cf}{2}\\
s'=f\frac{a+b+c}{2}\\
s'=fs
$$

And here is the area $A'$:

$$
A'=\sqrt{sf(sf-af)(sf-bf)(sf-cf)}\\
A'=\sqrt{sf^4(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\\
A'=f^2\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\\
A'=f^2A
$$

The length of the inradius $r'$ of the similar triangel is

$$
r'=\frac{A'}{s'}=\frac{f^2A}{fs}=f\frac{A}{s}\\
r'=fr
$$

So, when you stretch all sides of the triangle by the same factor, then also the inradius is stretched by the same factor.

Answer (score 0):

Note $A=rs$. If we scale up the triangle, the area scales by the square of the side length (a triangle is a 2-dimensional shape). The semiperimeter is a linear combination of the sides, so it scales up linearly. Then the scale of $r$ is $2-1=1$, so it scales up linearly as well.